# In a ListPlot of LinearModelFit, Fill to the regression line

Tags: plotting

In the help for LinearModelFit, the regression line can be added to the scatter plot like this:

```
Show[ListPlot[data], Plot[lm[x], {x, 0, 5}]]
```

Is it possible to fill from the points to the regression line?  This can illustrate the distance whose sum of squares is being minimized.  I tried variations on this:

```
Filling -> Table[ lm[data[[i]][[2]]],  {i, Length[data]}]]
```

Here the Table will be a list of predicted values for y at each observation of x, but this results in the error "not a valid filling specification."

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
data = Table[{x, .5 + .5 x + RandomReal[{-.5, .5}]}, {x, 
    RandomReal[7, 100]}];
lm = LinearModelFit[data, x, x];
ListPlot[{data, Table[{x,lm[x]}, {x, 0, 7, .1}]}, Joined -> {False, True}, 
    Filling -> 1 -> {2}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 9):

Another way, using the properties of `LinearModelFit`, and a convoluted way for constructing lines (note that all the plot is done with only one `ListLinePlot`)

```
verba = Table[{x, .5 + .5 x + RandomReal[{-.5, .5}]}, {x, RandomReal[7, 100]}];
lm = LinearModelFit[verba, x, x];
res = Transpose@{verba[[All, 1]], lm["PredictedResponse"]};
ListLinePlot[Flatten[Transpose@{res, verba, res}, 1], Mesh -> All, Frame -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: (+1) could also use `lm["PredictedResponse"]` instead of `#[[2]] - lm["FitResiduals"]` when defining `res`.

Comment: @kguler thanks! Edited.

Answer (score 8):

Another possibility, using `ErrorBar` :

```
Needs["ErrorBarPlots`"]

data = Table[{x, .5 + .5 x + RandomReal[{-.5, .5}]}, {x, 
RandomReal[{-5, 5}, 20]}];lm = LinearModelFit[data, x, x];

dataAndError = {#, ErrorBar[(-#[[2]] + lm[#[[1]]]) {Boole[#[[2]] >= lm[# [[1]]]] , Boole[#[[2]] < lm[#[[1]]]] }]} & /@ data;

Show[Plot[lm[x], {x, -5, 5}, PlotStyle -> {Red}], ErrorListPlot[dataAndError]]
```

[image: plot]

Answer (score 3):

One may simply draw them as follows.
This is the list of data:

```
lst = Table[{i, 0.5 + 0.5*i^(1/2) + RandomReal[{-.5, .5}]}, {i, 1, 10}]
```

This is the fitting:

```
ft = FindFit[lst, a*x^(1/2) + b, {{a, 0.4}, b}, x]
```

And this draws the fitting function together with the list and draws lines from the points specified by the list to the curve:

```
f[x_] := a*x^(1/2) + b /. ft
lst1 = Transpose[lst][[1]];

Show[{ListPlot[lst, PlotStyle -> Red], Plot[f[x] /. ft, {x, 0, 10}],


Graphics[   
     {Pink, Line[Transpose[{lst, Transpose[{lst1, Map[f, lst1]}]
                                              }]]} ]}]
```

That is the outcome:
[image]

Comment: `lst1 = Transpose[lst][[1]];` can also be done this way: `lst1 = lst[[All, 1]];`

Answer (score 2):

Yet another possibility, using `Arrow[]`+`Arrowheads[]`:

```
(* for reproducibility *)
BlockRandom[SeedRandom[42, Method -> "Legacy"];
            data = Sort[Table[{x, .5 + .5 x + RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[]]/5},
                              {x, RandomReal[7, 100]}]]];

lm = LinearModelFit[data, x, x];

Show[Graphics[{ColorData[1, 1], 
               Arrowheads[{{Automatic, Automatic, Graphics[Point[{0, 0}]]}}], 
               MapThread[Arrow[{##}] &,
                         {Transpose[{data[[All, 1]], lm["PredictedResponse"]}], data}]}],
     Plot[lm[x], {x, 0, 7}], Frame -> True]
```

[image: regression line and data points]