# In a ListPlot of LinearModelFit, plot error band

Tags: plotting, fitting

This is similar to [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/11328/534) question.

The fitted line can be plotted alongside with the data with this code:

```
Show[ListPlot[data], Plot[lm[x], {x, 0, 5}]]
```

I would like to include a band around this line indicating the average error. How can I do this?

**Example data:**

{{0.300369, 0.316832}, {0.450271, 0.485149}, {0.327772, 0.435644}, {0.573727, 0.594059}, {0.966333, 0.940594}, {0.5,0.356436}, {0.648136, 0.663366}, {0.830708, 0.831683}, {0.932212,0.950495}, {0.616441, 0.663366}, {0.616441, 0.613861}, {0.351864,0.415842}, {0.858684, 0.881188}, {0.626629, 0.554455}, {0.781502,0.841584}, {0.24901, 0.178218}, {0.776995, 0.811881}, {0.327772,0.405941}, {0.288312, 0.336634}, {0.60677, 0.663366}, {0.81564,0.811881}, {0.5, 0.455446}, {0.5, 0.60396}, {0.0592884,0.108911}, {0.951739, 0.940594}, {0.376411, 0.346535}, {0.5,0.435644}, {0.288312, 0.346535}, {0.781502, 0.831683}, {0.5,0.485149}, {0.5474, 0.584158}, {0.990885, 0.980198}, {0.376411,0.435644}, {0.937525, 0.980198}, {0.5, 0.455446}, {0.763858,0.841584}, {0.845342, 0.821782}, {0.616441, 0.70297}, {0.0158381,0.039604}, {0.836982, 0.881188}, {0.634059, 0.683168}, {0.258183,0.277228}, {0.867029, 0.80198}, {0.937525, 0.910891}, {0.130091,0.168317}, {0.971463, 0.990099}, {0.5, 0.455446}, {0.782699,0.792079}, {0.60314, 0.60396}, {0.977697, 0.960396}, {0.81564,0.90099}, {0.60677, 0.623762}, {0.39686, 0.455446}, {0.573727,0.574257}, {0.4526, 0.435644}, {0.5, 0.455446}, {0.236142,0.346535}, {0.5, 0.514851}, {0.60314, 0.584158}, {0.648136,0.693069}, {0.426273, 0.554455}, {0.373371, 0.465347}, {0.60314,0.524752}, {0.60677, 0.534653}, {0.383559, 0.524752}, {0.300369,0.277228}, {0.895366, 0.950495}, {0.426273, 0.455446}, {0.39323,0.29703}, {0.320827, 0.39604}, {0.979305, 0.990099}, {0.19846,0.207921}, {0.951739, 0.980198}, {0.0141859, 0.019802}, {0.265205,0.316832}, {0.783454, 0.831683}, {0.351864, 0.366337}, {0.763858,0.792079}, {0.648136, 0.673267}, {0.763858, 0.762376}, {0.678731,0.693069}, {0.376411, 0.376238}, {0.5, 0.514851}, {0.70727,0.712871}, {0.763858, 0.772277}, {0.5, 0.574257}, {0.258183,0.386139}, {0.893117, 0.831683}, {0.478985, 0.376238}, {0.104634,0.168317}, {0.235301, 0.188119}, {0.727486, 0.851485}, {0.327772,0.277228}, {0.5, 0.425743}, {0.648136, 0.712871}, {0.161454,0.158416}, {0.812018, 0.772277}, {0.365941, 0.39604}, {0.426273,0.485149}, {0.478985, 0.49505}}

```
lm = LinearModelFit[data, x, x]

Show[ListPlot[data, Plot[lm[x], {x, 0, 1}, PlotStyle -> Red], AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In addition to @lalmeis answer (and thanks to @ubpdqn for his response [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/47399/least-square-fitting)) we can work out additional information and learn more about the procedure:

with `lm ["Properties"]` we learn more about the underlying properties and can apply this also;

```
{"AdjustedRSquared", "AIC", "AICc", "ANOVATable", \
    "ANOVATableDegreesOfFreedom", "ANOVATableEntries", \
    "ANOVATableFStatistics", "ANOVATableMeanSquares", \
    "ANOVATablePValues", "ANOVATableSumsOfSquares", "BasisFunctions", \
    "BetaDifferences", "BestFit", "BestFitParameters", "BIC", \
    "CatcherMatrix", "CoefficientOfVariation", "CookDistances", \
    "CorrelationMatrix", "CovarianceMatrix", "CovarianceRatios", "Data", \
    "DesignMatrix", "DurbinWatsonD", "EigenstructureTable", \
    "EigenstructureTableEigenvalues", "EigenstructureTableEntries", \
    "EigenstructureTableIndexes", "EigenstructureTablePartitions", \
    "EstimatedVariance", "FitDifferences", "FitResiduals", "Function", \
    "FVarianceRatios", "HatDiagonal", "MeanPredictionBands", \
    "MeanPredictionConfidenceIntervals", \
    "MeanPredictionConfidenceIntervalTable", \
    "MeanPredictionConfidenceIntervalTableEntries", \
    "MeanPredictionErrors", "ParameterConfidenceIntervals", \
    "ParameterConfidenceIntervalTable", \
    "ParameterConfidenceIntervalTableEntries", \
    "ParameterConfidenceRegion", "ParameterErrors", "ParameterPValues", \
    "ParameterTable", "ParameterTableEntries", "ParameterTStatistics", \
    "PartialSumOfSquares", "PredictedResponse", "Properties", "Response", \
    "RSquared", "SequentialSumOfSquares", "SingleDeletionVariances", \
    "SinglePredictionBands", "SinglePredictionConfidenceIntervals", \
    "SinglePredictionConfidenceIntervalTable", \
    "SinglePredictionConfidenceIntervalTableEntries", \
    "SinglePredictionErrors", "StandardizedResiduals", \
    "StudentizedResiduals", "VarianceInflationFactors"}

lm[{"BestFit", "ParameterTable"}]
```

[image]

with

```
lm["ParameterConfidenceIntervals", ConfidenceLevel -> .999]
{{-0.0135474, 0.0777594}, {0.896584, 1.04648}}
```

respectively

```
lm["ParameterConfidenceIntervals", ConfidenceLevel -> .65]
{{0.019469, 0.044743}, {0.950786, 0.992278}}
```

you can estimate what happens to the bands. Perhaps the information from

```
lm["MeanPredictionBands"]
```

gives you additional information:
[image]

The following is from [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/howto/GetResultsForFittedModels.html)

> First, define functions for the 80%, 90%, 95%, and 99% prediction
>   bands of the fitted function:

```
{bands80[x_], bands90[x_], bands95[x_], bands99[x_]} = 
 Table[lm["SinglePredictionBands", 
   ConfidenceLevel -> cl], {cl, {.8, .9, .95, .99}}]
```

> Visualize the regions bounded by the bands along with the fitted
>   function and use Filling to more easily see the regions of each
>   confidence level:

```
Plot[{lm[x], bands80[x], bands90[x], bands95[x], bands99[x]}, {x, 0, 
  4}, Filling -> {2 -> {1}, 3 -> {2}, 4 -> {3}, 5 -> {4}}]
```

[image]

Alternatively, you can also apply the above-mentioned strategy:

```
p[x_] := lm["MeanPredictionBands", ConfidenceLevel -> 0.95]
Show[ListPlot[data], Plot[Evaluate@{lm[x], p[x]}, {x, 0, 1}]]
```

[image]

For "Confidence and Prediction Bands" check out [this](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/ConfidenceAndPredictionBands/) Demonstration.

Well, the red Line, the blue Line between the Bands ist the fit. But one can fiddle around with Plotstyle;

```
Plot[{lm[x], bands80[x], bands90[x], bands95[x], bands99[x]}, {x, 0, 
  4}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Thick, {Blue, Yellow, Green}}, 
 Filling -> {2 -> {1}, 3 -> {2}, 4 -> {3}, 5 -> {4}}]
```

[image]

Or one can of course use [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/25573/unexpected-behavior-of-confidence-bands-for-data-presenting-two-regions-with-une) answer (@Ziofil) to pimp the plot:

```
Show[ListPlot[data, PlotStyle -> {Opacity[0.5]}], 
 Plot[{lm[x], bands80[x], bands90[x], bands95[x], bands99[x]}, {x, 0, 
   1}, Filling -> {2 -> {{1}, Directive[{Green, Opacity[0.25]}]}, 
    3 -> {{2}, Directive[{Yellow, Opacity[0.75]}]}}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Directive[Thickness[0.0075], Blue], Green, Red}]]
```

[image]

---

**Edit:**

Since you have not accepted an answer, I would like to suggest an additional strategy: Take whatever values ​​as "average error". For example, "true standard deviation of the sample mean" (see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_error#Standard_error_of_the_mean)).

```
val1 = StandardDeviation[data[[All, 1]]]/Sqrt[Length[data]]
val2 = StandardDeviation[data[[All, 2]]]/Sqrt[Length[data]]
Show[ListPlot[data], Plot[{lm[x], lm[x + val1], lm[x - val2]}, {x, 0, 1}]]
```

[image]

Again you have "small" Bands, but you can adjust the Bands with your own, or different calculated values:

```
myerr1 = 0.2
myerr2 = 0.2
Show[ListPlot[data], Plot[{lm[x], lm[x + myerr1], lm[x - myerr2]}, {x, 0, 1}, 
  Filling -> {2 -> {3}}]]
```

[image]

Comment: I still wait to upvote both answers because it is difficult for me to distinguish the fit (which was red in the question) from the bands.

Comment: @eldo adding some spice and pimp ...

Answer (score 5):

You can get a function of confidence bands,for `LinearModelFit` and other Fit objects. Assuming `lm` is the Fit object, then:

```
 lm["MeanPredictionBands",ConfidenceLevel->.90][x]
```

You can then use the Filling option of `Plot` to get an actual band. 
With the data you provided:

```
lm = LinearModelFit[data11, x, x]
yourbands[x_] = lm["MeanPredictionBands", ConfidenceLevel -> 0.68]
Show[ListPlot[data11], 
   Plot[{lm[x], yourbands[x]}, {x, 0, 1.0}, Filling -> {2 -> {1}}]]
```

[image]

Comment: I added some example data to the question. Can you post the full code?

Comment: Why are the bands so thin?

Comment: I used 68% confidence level, (i.e. one standard deviation for a gaussian distribution). If you use 90% CL is will be larger.